# menu items not displaying properly

Tags: .net, menuitem

I am using Xml Data source to build menu for my application.. but the problem I am facing is, when i click on the menu it display all submenu right below the menu.. but when i scroll down a little in the page and click on the menu it display the menu items not at the right place.. which means it display the items not right below the menu it leaves some space in between (which is equal to legth i come down using scrollbar)..
can any one help me???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using frames or divs to arrange your sub-menus?  It sounds like they are arranged absolutely instead of relatively.  I'd start looking there.

Comment: Hi, I am using Infragistic ultra web menu for the same